# Apollo query returns error "Expected String, found String"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

I'm trying to get single product from DB, but all the time I'm getting the error: 
"Expected String, found String" from GraphQL.

Here is the code:

```js
class ProductDetail extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props.id));
    return <Query query={GET_PRODUCT} variables={{_id: JSON.stringify(this.props.id)}}>
    {({ loading, error, data }) => {
      if (loading) return <ReactLoading type="spin" className="spinner" color={"black"}></ReactLoading>
      if (error) return <Alert color="danger">{error.message}</Alert>
      return (
        <div>
          {data.products.map(p => (
            console.log(data)
          ))}
        </div>
      )
    }}
  </Query>
  }
}


const GET_PRODUCT = gql`
    {
  product(_id: String) {
    brand
  }
}
`

export default ProductDetail;
```

I noticed $ sign in query defining, tried with that but it returns: 
"Expected String, found $".

Comment: As a side note, you don't need to stringify `this.props.id`. And it looks like your query is meant to return a single product, but inside your `Query` component, you're actually mapping multiple ones. But that's irrelevant to your actual question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're conflating the operation signature and the field signature. The very first line of a GraphQL query has this format:

> [*operationType*] [*operationName*] [(*variableDefinitions*)]

If the operation type is omitted, it's assumed to be `query` (as opposed to `mutation` or `subscription`). The operation name is also optional. It's good practice to always include **both** when writing your queries.

*If* you have variables, their definitions follow the operation name and take the following format:

> *name*: *type* [= *defaultValue*]

Variable names always begin with `$`. Once declared, they can then be used in place of any argument inside your query. Just like variable definitions, field arguments are also wrapped in a set of parentheses, but their format is simply:

> *argumentName*: value

So, a query can look like this:

```
query SomeArbitraryName ($foo: String, $bar: Int!) {
  getSomething (name: $foo) {
    name
    quxs (max: $bar)
  }
}
```

Here we've defined two variables (`$foo` and `$bar`). `$foo` is used for the `name` argument for the `getSomething` query, while `$bar` is used as the `max` argument for the `quxs` field. Note that the types you define for each variable are significant -- I can only use `$foo` as a replacement for arguments that are of the type `String` (as opposed to another scalar or type or `String!` or `[String]`)

Normally, you end up with one variable per argument, so convention is to just use the argument name for the variable name, and just append the `$`, but the variable name could be anything you want.

Putting it all together, your query should look something like this:

```
query WhateverNameYouLike ($_id: String) {
  product(_id: $_id) {
    brand
  }
}
```

You could change the variable name to something else, like `$productId`, but you would also need to change how you reference that inside your `Query` component

Comment: Awesome! Please also upvote the answer if you found it helpful :)