# I get following error: expected Name, found $ when firing a GraphQL query from React using Apollo. The query works fine in GraphiQL

Tags: react-apollo, graphql-js, gql

Here's the GraphQL Query:

```
const movieByName = gql`
  query SomeName($name: String!){
    movieByName(name: $name){
      name
      genre
      year
    }
  }`
```

It works fine on graphiql though and here's the Schema

```
  type Query {
    movies: [Movie],
    movieByName(name: String!): Movie
  }
  type Movie {
    name: String,
    genre: String,
    year: String
  }
```

Here's the final code file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {HashLink as Link} from 'react-router-hash-link' 
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import { gql } from "apollo-boost";


const movieByName = gql`
  query SomeName($name: String!){
    movieByName(name: $name){
      name
      genre
      year
    }
  }`

class Header extends Component {
  state = {
    name: '',
    genre: '',
    year: ''
}

searchSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log(this.props)
}

render(){
  return (
    <div className="topnav">
      <a className="logo" href="/">Movie Maker</a>
      <div className="search-container">
        <form onSubmit={this.searchSubmit}>
          <Link smooth to="#form">Add Movies</Link>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search" 
            onChange={(e) => this.setState({name: e.target.value})}/>
          <button type="submit"><i className="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}}


export default graphql(movieByName)(Header)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apollo query returns error "Expected String, found String"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50246927/apollo-query-returns-error-expected-string-found-string)

Comment: @DanielRearden I typed the optional 'query' before the query name. It works but there's a new error: Variable "$name" of required type "String!" was not provided. I'm also providing the variables to query here:     this.props.movieByName({
      variables: {
        name: "John"
      }
    }) by using compose as here: export default compose(
  graphql(movieByName, {name: "movieByName"})
)(Header)

Comment: Your original query, as shown above, is indeed missing the `query` keyword but it also has an extra pair of curly brackets around it.

Comment: Sir, Please check the final code file also. I made changes as you said but still the same error: String was not provided